# How to make the android app offline using Google maps? or download the Map area in Android app using Google maps for an offline use?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am making a navigation app and have done all the work for which internet is required. I mean (I have drawn markers, made a route between them and other facilities like searching places of interest with reference to the users location) etc etc using Google map Android API v2.

But now I want to make that app offline too. I mean so that the user can do these things without internet connections. If search facility is possible in offline mode (I mean if markers cannot be drawn, route cannot be made between start and destination) then please tell me how it is possible.

And if it is not possible then how can I download the whole area of the map which shows the route the user has made using the app in online mode?

Comment: If it is possible at all (and im not sure it is), people are going to want to see what code you have tried in order to help you any further. Questions simply asking "Show me how to do this!" are frowned upon.

Comment: as i say brother for online mode my work is complete. it is working fine just as google map app but to make it offline and to achieve this  i need the help of the developer and experts here how to do that or achieve that thing because i am searching about two days n find different reviews that it is not possible so i am asking the developer here that is it true or not ??? if not then guide me how to do it .

Comment: I do recall that several years ago you could download maps that were importable and certainly used in our case for offline manipulation.  However, I cannot recall if this was done through Google Maps API at the time...I believe it was.  It just might have included special map tiles for a specific region downloaded ahead of time with prior knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-use-google-maps-offline-on-ios-android/) is an article talking about offline maps for **iOS** and **Android**. 
You could save the maps you want and work on the saved map files for your project.
[This](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps) is the latest version of Google Maps for Android, download it and scroll to the bottom of the page to find a section dedicated to offline maps. You can now save a map by:

**1.** Typing "OK Maps" while viewing any map.
 **2.** In the settings menu.

Note that this only saves maps for 30 days.

Comment: i already have google map installed on my android phone i am talking about building an offline android app that use google map in it

Comment: You would need to download a huge map to start with, and then all the road/path/river/rail etc data to map between points.

Comment: ya bennef thats the thing i am talking about if i download the map of specific region and it is stored on the sd card then how would i load that map could you tell me that plzzz

Answer (score 1):

You can use an OpenStreetMaps controller and Google Maps tiles. According to the Google Maps TOS (10.1.3.b), it seems that you can use a portion of maps if you cache it temporarily and securely.